# Linking pytorch c++ (prebuilt GPU version) with Qt and GCC

Tags: c++, qt, pytorch, libtorch

I wrote a simple program in C++ to use my PyTorch model in `libtorch 1.7.1`. I have CUDA 10.2 on my OS, thus
I downloaded CUDA 10.2 prebuilt version of `libtorch` from this [link](https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/cu102/libtorch-cxx11-abi-shared-with-deps-1.7.1.zip).
The program works fine with CMake and CUDA. CMake can load my model on GPU and returns "Yes" when I run this simple program:

[image]

Now, I would like to use the model in my Qt Application. It gives this result when I try it :

[image]

This is my project QMake file :

```
QT -= gui
CONFIG +=  c++14 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DGLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
CONFIG += no_keywords
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-unused-parameter
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -INCLUDE:?warp_size@cuda@at@@YAHXZ

INCLUDEPATH += /home/eaglesoft/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include
INCLUDEPATH += /home/eaglesoft/libtorch/include
DEPENDPATH +=  /home/eaglesoft/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include
DEPENDPATH +=  /home/eaglesoft/libtorch/include

LIBS += -L/home/eaglesoft/libtorch/lib -lc10 \
        -lc10_cuda \
        -lcaffe2_module_test_dynamic \
        -lcaffe2_observers \
        -ltorch_cpu \
        -ltorch \
        -lc10d_cuda_test \
        -lcaffe2_detectron_ops_gpu \
        -lcaffe2_nvrtc \
        -lfmt \
        -lnvrtc-builtins \
        -lshm \
        -ltensorpipe \
        -ltorch_cuda
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Forget about qmake. It’s a dead end. You already got a CMakeFile, adding Qt to that project is literally 5 lines: three for AUTOMOC/UIC/RCC, one for find package, one for linking with Qt modules needed. Qt has cmake support that covers Qt 4, Qt 5 and Qt 6. Cmake documentation details the use of the FindQt[4|5|6] package. That’s all you need. It’s lamentable that most people are misled by the documentation to think that Qt implies qmake. These days it’s a waste of time - good riddance :)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Im noob in CMake wtih Qt , and in this time I think it will take a while for me to bring CMake in Qt. Btw thx for your suggestion, I will try it.